# Getting Error - "ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2" if I do "Run as Java Application"

Tags: java, maven, log4j, log4j2

Getting the below error if I run my test/java class using "Run as Java Application" -

"ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console..."

Tried to run below code as Java Application in eclipse -

DataDriven.java file -

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class DataDriven {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C://Users//Shreyas Lembhe//OneDrive//Documents//DataDemo.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workBook=new XSSFWorkbook();
        
        int sheets=workBook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for(int i=0;i<sheets;i++) {
            if(workBook.getSheetName(i).equalsIgnoreCase("testdata")) {
                XSSFSheet sheet=workBook.getSheetAt(i);
                //Identify test case column by scanning the entire 1st row
                Iterator<Row> rows=sheet.iterator();
                Row firstRow=rows.next();
                Iterator<Cell> ce=firstRow.cellIterator();//Row is a collection of cells
                int k=0;
                int column = 0;
                while(ce.hasNext()) {
                    Cell value=ce.next();
                    if(value.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("testcases")) {
                        column=k;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                System.out.println(column);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

pom.xml file -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExcelDriver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-beta1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Getting the same error even if I remove the log4j dependency from above.

Comment: The versions of poi-ooxml and poi-ooxml-schemas should be in sync...

Comment: try to make plugins for log4j in pom.xml . dependency + plugin

Comment: thank you for your help. But it worked after changing the version of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

its a version problem, try this :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-spring-boot</artifactId>
<version>2.20.0</version>
```

Comment: Thank you @mohamed amine ben hassen. It worked

Comment: Good, i am happy that it worked can you accept my answer as the solution . thank you